# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Critical Values

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm conducting some research where I need the critical values of the one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov distribution. I've found a number of tables online, but the answers from these tables seem too high. Here's one example; all the tables I find online agree with this one: https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/GG/FACULTY/ITO/GG413/K_S_Table_one_Sample.pdf

I wrote my own code in R to try and verify these values through simulation. The code is shown below:

```r
ks_sim_crit <- function(n, alpha = .05, num_sims = 1000000) {

  ks_stat_vec <- numeric(num_sims)
  for(iter in seq(from = 1, to = num_sims, by = 1)) {

    iter_points <- runif(n = n)
    iter_ecdf <- ecdf(iter_points)
    ks_stat <- max(abs(iter_ecdf(iter_points) - iter_points))
    ks_stat_vec[iter] <- ks_stat

  }

  ks_stat_vec <- sort(ks_stat_vec)
  crit_val_index = round((1 - alpha) * num_sims)
  return(ks_stat_vec[crit_val_index])

}
```

When I run this code with n = 10 and the other default parameters I get a value of .377, where the table that I linked to suggests that the answer should be .409. Is there an error in my code or in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I think that because the KS value is the max of $D_{-}$ and $D_{+}$. In the truly continuous case is the absolute value of the difference between the empirical and true CDFs, but when using replications, it may not be. By passing only 10 items in each trial vector, the largest absolute value is not necessarily the same as the larger of the differences.

The following R code should create an example of where there is a difference:

```r
n <- 6
set.seed(8444)
A <- sort(runif(n))
Q <- data.frame(x = A,
                pm = (seq_len(n) - 1) / n,
                pp = seq_len(n) / n,
                Dm = A - 0:(n-1)/n,
                Dp = 1:n / n - A,
                KS = pmax(A - 0:(n-1)/n, 1:n / n - A),
                Incorrect = abs(pmax(1:n / n - A)))
```

This results in the following table:

```r
          x        pm        pp         Dm          Dp         KS  Incorrect
1 0.1240759 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.12407592  0.04259075 0.12407592 0.04259075
2 0.3783428 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.21167610 -0.04500944 0.21167610 0.04500944
3 0.5970873 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.26375395 -0.09708728 0.26375395 0.09708728
4 0.7214145 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.22141453 -0.05474786 0.22141453 0.05474786
5 0.7510212 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.08435453  0.08231214 0.08435453 0.08231214
6 0.8606864 0.8333333 1.0000000 0.02735306  0.13931361 0.13931361 0.13931361
```

The true KS value is 0.263 from the third element. The "shortcut" would fail and result in 0.139.

Here is some R code which should work, and is slightly faster than yours above:

```r
ks_val <- function(n) {
  vec <- runif(n)
  vec <- vec[order(vec)]
  p <- seq_len(n) / n
  # First element is D-minus getting i-1 / N by subtracting 1 / N from p
  # Second element is D-plus 
  max(pmax(vec - (p - 1 / n), p - vec))
}

ks_sim_crit2 <- function(n, alpha = .05, num_sims = 1e6) {
  sort.int(replicate(num_sims, ks_val(n)),
           na.last = TRUE)[round((1 - alpha) * num_sims)]
}
```

This results in:

```r
set.seed(12)
system.time(A <- ks_sim_crit2(10))
 user  system elapsed 
28.93    0.10   29.03 
A
[1] 0.4095176
```

Which is very close to the critical values in the table.